# Error on generate sitemap.xml -> dynamicRoutes.map is not a function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, sitemap, sitemap.xml

**Context:**

I'm using [Nuxt Sitemap Module](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/) and I'm trying to generate or create my dynamics routes (products that i have on my DB). Here is my sitemap on my nuxt.config.js

```js
sitemap: {
    hostname: process.env.PH_WEB_APP_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/',
    gzip: true,
    exclude: ExcludedPaths,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    defaults: {
      changefreq: 'daily',
      priority: 1,
      lastmod: new Date()
    },
    routes: () => {
      const baseUrl = process.env.PH_WEB_APP_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/';
      return axios.get(`${baseUrl}api/sitemap-slugs/`);
    }
  },
```

The endpoint `${baseUrl}api/sitemap-slugs/` returns an array of slugs ['slug1','slug2']

**Expected Result**

My sitemap.xml page with all my statics routes and my dynamic routes.

**ERROR**

Error on my http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml.
[image]

**I hope I have explained the situation and myself well**

Comment: Maybe try to `await` it before the `return`.

Comment: @kissu thanks but no, this could be an improvement (I also tried before), but the error is the same with or without `async, await`

Comment: Maybe return value type is not an array

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You have to use data property of axios response if it returns string array.

```html
routes: async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('https://www.example.com/api/blog-sitemap')
      return result.data;
 }
```